# Make view auto-resize in full screen when NSToolbar dragged down

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, fullscreen, nstoolbar

I hide the NSToolbar instance when my application enters full-screen. But I noticed when the toolbar is dragged (shown) in full screen mode, it blocked the upper part of my window's content view.

How can I make my content view auto-resized and unblocked when toolbar is shown in full screen mode?